# Couldn't load inserted library: Why do I get this random crash?

Tags: xcode, ios4, dylib

So the other day I went to compile my app and load it onto my device (iPhone SDK) and it compiled fine but while it was loading it crashed and in the console it gave me:

**dyld: could not load inserted library: /System/Library/Spotlight/libent.dylib**

It gives me this every time I try to load any app onto my iPod regardless if I am using cocos2D or the default Apple templates.  My apps compile fine most of the time on the simulator, although it does sometimes give me random Core Foundation errors for no reason.

I am using xcode 4.0.2, on Mac OSX Snow Leopard if that helps.
I tried reinstalling xcode as well.

This is really annoying and I hope someone knows a fix. :)

Thanks,
Tate

Comment: i have the same problem...have you find some solution?

Comment: @Mat: No, I haven't found a fix, but I found that it still puts the app on your device when you run it, even though its stuck at the loading screen and may not seem like it worked.  Its annoying, but at least it works...

Comment: Strange, I'm having this issue now too. App stays at the loading screen.

I even checked out my last commit (which was working) and tried to install that, same error (even though that commit replaced the project file and everything). Xcode is such a fail.